# Why did I become disable to use Oracle XE with error: "IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 17002"?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, listener

I am using Oracle 18c XE on my computer. Everything was okay with Oracle, but today I wanted to login in sqldeveloper with the following data on this picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi73T.png)

As you can see, I got the following error: `Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`.

`lsitener.ora` is:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\user\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\user\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <my computer>.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <my computer>.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <my computer>.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
```

Performing a test in Net Configuration Assistant, I get the following message:

```
Connecting...ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
The test did not succeed.

Some of the information you provided may be incorrect.
Click Back to review the information provided for net service name, or Change Login to change username.
```

How can I fix or reconfigure the listener? Why did it even ruined?

Comment: It probably got shutdown, do you see process/services running on your machine?

Comment: Do you mean e. g. in cmd? How can I check it there?

Comment: In windows control panel, services...or in cmd run, lsnrctl status or lsnrctl start...but your db needs to be running too, so sqlplus / as SYSDBA, then startup